# Angular 2 + angular-in-memory-web-api zone GET http://localhost:3000/traceur 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, api, angular, typescript

Hi I have a problem with angular-in-memory-web-api. I tried to use angular2-in-memory-web-api in SystemJS and another solutions her but with no result. I'm using official quickstart template. 
Thank you for help

Error list

```
zone.js:1382 GET http://localhost:3000/traceur 404 (Not Found)
dashboard:19 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading 
http://localhost:3000/traceur
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
    Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-web-api.module.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-web-api.module.js as "angular-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-web-api.module" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
    Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-web-api.module.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-web-api.module.js as "angular-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-web-api.module" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
```

My consignJS

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',

      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
    "docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.0",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings": "^1.4.0",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

App Module

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import { AppRoutingModule }     from './app-routing.module';
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-web-api.module';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';


import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroService }          from './hero.service';




@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent
  ],
  providers: [ HeroService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Version 0.1.13 of `angular2-in-memory-web-api` had some breaking changes and it looks like the tutorial has not been updated yet.

According to the changelog:

> In systemjs.config.js you should change the mapping to:
>
> `'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'`
>
> then delete from packages:
>
> `'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
>
>     main: './index.js',
>
>     defaultExtension: 'js'
>
>   }`

Link to the chang
https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0113-2016-10-20

An issue has also been filed https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/issues/58

It says to update `app.module.ts` by changing

`import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api/in-memory-web-api.module';`

to

`import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';`

Answer (score 2):

Even after I tried everything mentioned before I still got this error:

`"originalStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js\n\tError: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js\n\t    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:889:29) [<root>]\n\t    at Zone.runTask (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [<root> => <root>]`

Then I realized, that it **only occurs during tests** with karma (no ... I do not try start the server if tests fail).

This worked for me:

- systemjs.config.js as described by others here (and meanwhile fixed in original sample code): `'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',`
- karma.conf.js:

  `files: [
  (...)
  'node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
  (...)
  { pattern: 'node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
  ]`

additional I had to set a provider for `{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue:  "/" }` because karma doesn't use the index.html

finally all tests passed and I can do my "npm start" :-)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I was still getting the same error even after following @joel's answer and the issue on github.

In case if anyone is facing the same issue, follow the below steps:

Add the below line to the "map" object in the **systemjs.config.js** file

```
'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
```

Essentially, here you are pointing to the umd.js file which is present in your node_modules folder.

In the packages object of the **systemjs.config.js** file, add the below line

```
'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
```

These changes work only on versions greater than 0.1.13, Hence please verify in your **package.json** if "angular-in-memory-web-api" has a version greater than or equal to 0.1.13, i.e,

```
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For those following the tutorial, after I followed Joel's answer, it let me directly to another problem giving me the following error.

```
ctorParameters.map is not a function at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters
```

It let me to this answer: [Updating angular-in-memory-wep-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107962/angular-in-memory-web-api-ctorparameters-map-is-not-a-function)

I had to update the "angular-in-memory-web-api" from 0.1.13 to 0.2.0 in packages.json