# angular-in-memory-web-api: ctorParameters.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using 0.1.17 of the Angular2 In-Memrory API along with the Angular CLI (with Webpack). I followed all the steps verbatim from the [HTTP tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#in-mem-web-api) and I'm getting the following error:

```
reflection_capabilities.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function
    at ReflectionCapabilities.parameters (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:48626:45)
```

Here is my app.module.js imports:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    CoreModule,

    // Fake API -- remove for production
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)
  ],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, that your versions don't match. The angular version you are using wants ctorParameters to be an array. But in InMemoryWebApiModule v0.1.17 there is a function provided. Upgrade to v0.2.0. In this version an array is provided.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't try your solution, but apparently upgrading to the most recent version (0.2.0) of the in-memory-web-api module fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown, when you put wrong sign in a template `==` instead of `=` in a parameter assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This bug seems to be linked to some package expecting the version of Angular core to be different than what is actually installed.

I was able to figure out the cause of this issue by looking at the error report from `ng build`:

```
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.4.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.4 but none was installed.
```

This helped me realize that one of my packages expected Angular to be at v2.4.4, but I'm using v2.0.1. I updated my package.json to have both packages set to my core version like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "2.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.1",
}
```

Your issue might not be with @angular/platform-server, but I hope this helps debug it