# Uncaught TypeError: ctorParameters.map is not a function for angular2-toaster

Tags: angular

```
"@angular/common": "~2.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.1.2",
"@angular/core": "~2.1.2",
"@angular/forms": "~2.1.2",
"@angular/http": "~2.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.2",
"@angular/router": "~3.1.2",
"@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.2",
"angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.17",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.2",
"moment": "^2.17.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
"angular2-toaster": "^2.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"systemjs": "0.19.40",
"zone.js": "^0.6.26"
```

This is the from the package.json, also added angular2-toaster in systemjs.config.js. Have tried also a different kind of toaster(ng2-toastr) and got the same thing.

Comment: are you sure its not this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107962/angular-in-memory-web-api-ctorparameters-map-is-not-a-function ?

Comment: yes, i've updated to the latest in memory web api and i still get the same error

Comment: seems to be common error with a lot of packages.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285889/ctorparameters-map-is-not-a-function-in-angular2-mdl answers are a little detailed

Comment: Looks like it's this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ctorParameters.map is not a function in angular2-mdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285889/ctorparameters-map-is-not-a-function-in-angular2-mdl)